# How would you go about auto-detecting Textile versus Markdown?

Tags: php, javascript, markdown, textile

I'm considering supporting both **[Textile](http://textism.com/tools/textile/)** and **[Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)** on a current project. I would prefer not forcing users to choose one or the other. Is there a way to auto-detect which the user is using? How would you go about this? I'd like to find / develop both a JavaScript and a PHP solution so I can provide live previews as well as process the user input on the server-side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider that users might only use one specific syntax element in a posting, so you'd have to check for everything. Looking for "h1." obviously only works if the user uses exactly that element.

It's pretty easy with things like headers, but consider that markdown formats `*this*` as `<em>this</em>` and Textile will convert that to `<strong>this</strong>` instead. So you'd have ambiguous syntax constructs that would yield different results in each language.

I'd suggest going with a user choice. Try to find out what syntax is generally preferred by your users (or you), offer an "use x instead of y" checkbox for those who want the other choice.

Answer (score 3):

This really shouldn't be that hard. Markdown does not support the following syntax;

```
h1. Header

p. Paragraph
```

... so you simply scan for that to check if it is textile. Very simple regular expression to get you started (scans for lines beginning with hX. or p.) in PHP code:

```
if (preg_match('/^(p|h[1-6])\. /m', $subject)) 
{
    // Successful match
} else 
{
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

You will probably be able to write your own regex to scan for Markdown.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-detection, I don't know, both are based on "natural" typing.
Perhaps you can ask the user to choose a format, with a pair of radio-buttons or something.